# How can I find the minecraft.jar in 1.8+

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to find minecraft.jar, but the only thing I can find is *insert version here*.json. Not .jar. 
Where is the jar file?

Comment: Any mod that requires you to find `minecraft.jar` will not work with 1.8+. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: That is true, upvoted, but he didn't explicitly mean "mods".

Comment: @ardaozkal Yep. Hence the request for fuller information instead of just help with this one corner of whatever they're attempting.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie added your comment to my answer and mentioned you, is it ok?

Comment: @ardaozkal It's all good.

Answer (score 2):

The jar files were moved to the versions folder, starting by the new launcher.

On my computer, it's on:

```
%appdata%\.minecraft\versions\1.8\1.8.jar
```

Also, [SevenSidedDie](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/4163/sevensideddie) just mentioned the fact that any mod that requires you to find minecraft.jar will not work with 1.8+.